# Automorphism of the subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

> Let $G$ a finite group and $H<G$. Let $\varphi:H\rightarrow H$ be a nontrivial automorphism of $H$. My question is: it is possible to construct a nontrivial automorphism of $G$?

I had tried to extend the isomorphism of H, leaving invariant the elements of G that were not in H. But you can take the next case: if $a,b\in G$ such that $a,b\notin H$ and $ab\in H$, so $\varphi(ab)\in H$ but not necessarily $\varphi(ab)=ab$. So my idea is wrong.

I must demonstrate this using the non-trivial automorphism of $H$.

Comment: Do you want to show that there exists a nontrivial automorphism (in this case see the link above) or that $\varphi$ can be extended to $G$ ?

Comment: I want to build an automorphism based

Comment: It is a strange question, because you assume the existence of an automorphism $\varphi$ of $H$, but then you ask whether there exists an automorphism of $G$ that apparently has nothing to do with $\varphi$. But in fact the existence of $\varphi$ implies that $|H|>2$ and hence $|G|>2$, so the answer to the question is yes.

Comment: I think they want an automorphism $\phi^*$ of $G$ such that its restriction to $H$ is $\phi$.

Comment: If the question is about whether all automorphisms of $H$ are restrictions of automorphisms of $G$, then see [Are there automorphisms of $H$ which are not restriction of an automorphism of $G$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586844/are-there-automorphisms-of-h-which-are-not-restriction-of-an-automorphism-of?rq=1)

Comment: Oh, I see now @GregorySimon. Thank you.